HomoValueList of template arguments is not working
The thing is that I have encountered a piece of code in a book entitled C++17 Complete Guide by Nicolai M. Josuttis, p.122. That code snippet does not work with me. I wonder why.
template<auto V1, decltype(V1)... VS>
class HomoValueList {
};

The author claims that such a declaration should forbid non homogeneous template arguments. But in reality I cannot produce an error:
int main() {
  HomoValueList<1, 'a', true> vals4; // Must be an error according to the author but not for me.
  return 0;
}


You get implicit conversions here.

@HolyBlackCat I wonder if something has changed since the issue of the C++17 standard since the author claims that the exact line must be forbidden.

In C++20 you could replace decltype(V1)... VS with std::same_as<decltype(V1)> auto... VS to get your desired error. You can probably achieve something similar enough in C++17 using SFINAE + partial specialization

In C++17, the class template itself cannot be SFINAE, but it is possible to define a type alias template that is SFINAE-friendly:
template <auto V1, auto... VS>
struct list {};

template <auto V1, auto... VS>
using list_t = std::enable_if_t<
    std::conjunction_v<
        std::is_same<
            decltype(V1),
            decltype(VS)>...>,
    list<V1, VS...>>;

Compiler Explorer: https://godbolt.org/z/qPWxa4brG
I'd like to add that perhaps the author simply meant this is true:
template <auto V1, decltype(V1)... VS>
struct homogenous_list {};

template <class>
inline constexpr bool is_homogenous_v = false;

template <template <auto...> class Op, auto V1, auto... VS>
inline constexpr bool is_homogenous_v<Op<V1, VS...>> = std::conjunction_v<
    std::is_same<
        decltype(V1),
        decltype(VS)>...>;

static_assert(is_homogenous_v<homogenous_list<1, 'a', true>>);

Compiler Explorer: https://godbolt.org/z/sKoaG891v

Actually, the code in the book is exactly that one which I have shown in the topic start. But thanks!

@unegare fair enough, I haven't read the book myself, was just trying to give the author the benefit of doubt

This code compiles because of implicit conversions, so the book is wrong.

I wonder if something has changed since the issue of the C++17 standard since the author claims that the exact line must be forbidden.

I don't think so. The latest Clang, GCC, and MSVC all accept this code even in C++17 mode.
Here's a working C++20 alternative: (thanks @PatrickRoberts)
template <auto V1, auto ...VS>
requires (std::is_same_v<decltype(V1), decltype(VS)> && ...)
class HomoValueList
{};

Pre-C++20 you could use a static_assert, but note that it's not SFINAE-friendly.
template<auto V1, auto ...VS>
class HomoValueList
{
    static_assert((std::is_same_v<decltype(V1), decltype(VS)> && ...));
};


Also think it's worth pointing out that the static_assert isn't triggered until the template instantiation is ODR-used (i.e. the detector idiom would say it's well-formed rather than resulting in a compilation error)
